# Vue.js запрос к серверу перед инициализацией перменных

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Здравствуйте у меня вопрос, можно ли сделать так, чтобы сначала послать запрос на сервер принять его, и только потом инициализоровать все переменные data? На данный момент currentTask и countTasks инициализируются перед запросом к серверу, пример ниже:

```
...


data : {

    tasks : [],
    countTasks : tasks.length,

    currentTask : {
        title : tasks[0].title,
        description : tasks[0].description,
        inputData : tasks[0].inputData,
        outputData : tasks[0].outputData
    }

},
created : function () {

    var self = this;
    axios.get('/getTasks').then(function (response) {
        var tasksFromServer = response.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < tasksFromServer.length; i++) {
            self.tasks.push({
                title : tasksFromServer[i].title,
                description : tasksFromServer[i].description,
                inputData : tasksFromServer[i].inputData,
                outputData : tasksFromServer[i].outputData
            });
        }
    });

},

...
```

Может кто-нибудь подскажет что можно сделать или придумать, чтобы осуществить данныую идею? Заоранее спасибо...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запрос на сервер будет идти в любом случае куда дольше, чем миллисекунды, которые требуются на создание экземпляра.

До загрузки можно либо поставить заглушки, либо просто показать значок загрузки:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    data: []
  },
  beforeCreate: function () {
    new Promise((res, rej) => {
      setTimeout(_ => res(), 1000);
    }).then(res => {
      this.data = [
          [1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]
        ];
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  <table v-if='data.length'>
    <tr v-for='(row, i) in data' :key='i'>
      <td v-for='(cell, i) in row' :key='i'>{{ cell }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div v-else>Loading...</div>
</div>
```